# DAX way to get all column names of a table as a list

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way in DAX to get all column names of a table as a list of values? Say we have in a table with 3 columns:

```
col1 | col2 |col3
```

I want a dax table (or dax variable) that would retrieve those column names to a single column:

```
SingleColumn
----
col1
col2
col3
```

I know that there is solution in PowerQuery for that. I am interested in DAX solution.

Comment: I don't believe that it's possible to obtain column names using DAX.

Answer (score 5):

If you have deployed a PBI data model in a SSAS server, you can write following DAX query to retrieve all column names for all tables within that SSAS DB with

`EVALUATE COLUMNSTATISTICS()`

[image: S1]

[image: S2]

Can only be used as a DAX query